# How to change PATH for Makefile $(shell ...) commands?

Tags: makefile, path, environment-variables, gnu-make

When I run

```
export PATH := mypath
$(error $(shell echo "$${PATH}"))
```

it seems my `PATH` isn't changed on the call to `shell`.

Why is this and how do I actually change the `PATH` for `shell` calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this with GNU make?  There is a long-standing [GNU make feature request to honor exported variables with `$(shell …)`](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?10593).  This is not specific to `PATH` at all, it affects (or does not affect) all `export` variables.

According to the GNU make sources, this is tricky to implement:

```
  /* Using a target environment for 'shell' loses in cases like:
       export var = $(shell echo foobie)
       bad := $(var)
     because target_environment hits a loop trying to expand $(var) to put it
     in the environment.  This is even more confusing when 'var' was not
     explicitly exported, but just appeared in the calling environment.

     See Savannah bug #10593.

  envp = target_environment (NULL);
  */
```

Comment: Oof... I was afraid of this. Thank you. +1 For what it's worth I think even allowing `export` with a delay-expanded variable makes absolutely no sense, but who am I to judge GNU...

Comment: I don't see why it makes no sense.  The variable could be something like `export TARGET = $@` to force the `$TARGET` environment variable to be set to the target name, or something like that.  Anyway, to do what you want you have to include the setting inside the shell invocation: `$(shell PATH=$(PATH); run my command)`

Comment: @MadScientist: Well if I do `export PATH = $(shell curl example.com)` `$(info $(shell foo ...))` `$(info $(shell bar ...))` how many requests am I supposed to get to `example.com`? One? two? three...? You don't need to be inside a rule to call `$(shell ...)`, it's something that's legal at Makefile parse time (and incidentally that's what I need it for).

Comment: Uh... what?  You're trying to set your `PATH` to the value returned by running `curl example.com`?  I don't understand your comment and I think you didn't understand mine.  You have `$(error $(shell echo $$PATH))`.  What I'm saying is that if you want the shell script to have your setting of `PATH` you have to include it in the script; e.g., write that as `$(error $(shell PATH=$(PATH); echo $$PATH))` instead (yes I realize the echo is not what you want to do: replace it with whatever command you want to run).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: never ever use `$(shell)` or `export`.

Environment variables should be part of the recipe that needs them.

For `$(shell)` invocations that are supposed to fill a makefile variable you can use instead.

- it also has the advantage to be more flexible, because you can fill more than one variable with one recipe
- you can also define proper dependencies, whereas `$(shell)` is always executed, either when the makefile is parsed or the recursively expanded variable gets expanded.
- you get build errors and recipes are logged, whereas `$(shell)` can make the DevOp engineers life a living h...

```makefile
PATH := mypath

Makefile.variables:
    @PATH=$(PATH) echo "This my path '$${PATH}'"
    echo >$@ "MY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT := abcd"

include Makefile.variables

$(info MY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT '$(MY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT)')
```

Example run:

```
$ make
MY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT ''
This my path 'mypath'
echo >Makefile.variables "MY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT := abcd"
MY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT 'abcd'
make: 'Makefile.variables' is up to date.
```

Comment: I agree `$(shell)` is overused :-). Yeah, there are places where it is the right thing, but these are few and far between. I usually take it as a smell, the makefile is usually improved once removed.